# Ordenar valores CSV Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Tengo el siguiente codigo que me crea un CSV con data obtenida a partir de otro CSV. En esta imagen muetro mis resultados:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, lo que busco es que el nuevo csv en vez de grabarse con todos los datos, primero me ordene los datos de mayor a menor en cuanto a impresiones y solo me muestre el top 20. Algo asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo:

```
import csv
input_file = 'report_2017_12_11_12_31_19UTC.csv'
output_file= "All_Data_Tags.csv"

with open(input_file) as csvfile, open(output_file,  "w") as output:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    cols = ("domain","ddomain","opportunities", "impressions", "fillRate", "DATA")
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=cols, extrasaction='ignore')

    writer.writeheader()
    for row in reader:
        row['fillRate'] = '{:.2f}'.format(float(row['fillRate']) * 100)
        if row['ddomain']  == "":
            if row['domain']  == "":
                row['ddomain'] = "App"
                row['domain'] = " "
        if row['domain'] == row['ddomain']:
            row['domain'] = "Real Site"    
        if row['domain']  == "":
            row['domain'] = "Detected Only"
        if row['ddomain']  == "":
            row['ddomain'] = "Vast Media"
        if row['ddomain'] != row['domain']:
            if row['ddomain'] != "Vast Media":
                if row['domain'] != "Real Site":
                    if row['domain'] != "Detected Only":
                        if row['ddomain'] != "App":
                            row['DATA'] = "FAKE"
                        else:
                            row['DATA'] = "OK"
                    else:
                        row['DATA'] = "OK"
                else:
                    row['DATA'] = "OK"
            else:
                row['DATA'] = "OK"

        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: @FJSevilla creo que sabes hacer esto

Answer (score 1):

De esta manera con pandas logre lo que buscaba. Saludos

```
import pandas as pd 


movies = pd.read_csv('Top20_Media_Yesterday.csv')

movies = movies.sort_values(['impressions'], ascending=False)

movies = movies.to_csv("Top20_Media_Yesterday.csv")

movies = pd.read_csv('Top20_Media_Yesterday.csv', nrows=21)

movies = movies.to_csv("Top20_Media_Yesterday.csv")
```

Comment: Si en vez de números, tuviese palabras y quisiera ordenarlas por orden alfabético, como se haría?

Answer (score 0):

Deberás almacenar primero el csv en memoria, preferiblemente en una lista (ordenable y mutable), luego aplicas `list.sort` para que ordene por la columna que quieras y por último iteras solo sobre las 20 primeras filas de la lista.

```
import csv
import operator


input_file = 'report_2017_12_11_12_31_19UTC.csv'
output_file= "All_Data_Tags.csv"

with open(input_file) as csvfile, open(output_file,  "w") as output:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    cols = ("domain","ddomain","opportunities", "impressions", "fillRate", "DATA")
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=cols, extrasaction='ignore')
    rows = sorted(reader, reverse=True, key=operator.itemgetter('impressions'))[:20]

    writer.writeheader()
    for row in rows:

        # Resto del código igual
```

La clave está en :

```
sorted(reader, reverse=True, key=operator.itemgetter('impressions'))[:20]
```

Que nos retorna una lista ordenada en orden descendente (`reverse=True`) en función de la columna `impressions` (clave `impressions` de cada diccionario que conforma cada fila y que es retornada por `operator.itemgetter`).

Si requieres más rendimiento porta el código para usar Pandas.

Comment: agregue otra respuesta recien con pandas, si podes chequearla seria genial. Pude lograr lo que necesitaba!

Comment: Si es correcto, es a lo  comentaba al final de mi respuesta, solo que yo no cargaría el csv en Pandas solo para ordenar . Ya que cargas el csv en memoria con Pandas lo normal sería crear el csv de salida también en Pandas aprovechando que tienes los datos cargados y no volver a cargarlo en Python estándar, lo cual crea una sobrecarga importante que se puede evitar. Por cierto guardas el csv de salida con todas las filas, lo cargas de nuevo y lo sobrescribes con solo las primeras 20 filas. Aplica el  `nrows=21` en el primer `movies.to_csv("Top20_Media_Yesterday.csv")` no vuelvas a cargar el csv

Comment: okey, y sabes como renombrar un header del csv?

Comment: @MartinBouhie con pandas puedes cambiar el nombre de las columnas con `pandas.DataFrame.rename`. Por ejemplo para renombrar tu columna `fillRate` haces `movies.rename(columns={'fillRate': 'New_fillRate'}, inplace=True)` o al escribir el csv pasale una lista con los nombres de tus columnas al argumento `header` de `to_csv`. En Python con el módulo csv puedes simplemente escribir tu propio header, en vez de `writer.writeheader()` puedes hacer `writer.writerow(dict(zip(writer.fieldnames, ("domain","ddomain","opportunities", "impressions", "new_fillRate", "DATA"))))`.